# htaccess redirect for a subfolder of a certain domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Domain an a Subdomain:

www.domain.com (Desktop Website)
m.domain.com (Mobile Website)

### Now i want to redirect a certain folder and all its pages, but only for m.domain.com.

for example (url of a certain news entry):
DESKTOP: www.domain.com/news/topic/detail/news.html [everything fine]

MOBILE: m.domain.com/news/opic/detail/news.html

This is the mobiel URL. Now there should be a redirect of the folder "topic" to the folder news, but only in the mobile version.

### The final url should be m.domain.com/news/detail/news.html

How can i only set the rule for a certain folder of only one domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your Root/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^news/topic/detail/(.*)/?$ http://m.domain.com/news/detail/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

This redirects

```
domain.com/news/topic/detail/news.html
```

to

```
 m.domain.com/news/detail/news.html
```